# Product of consecutive numbers f(n) = n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n- ...) find the value of n

Tags: algorithm, math

Is there a way to find **programmatically** the consecutive natural numbers?

On the Internet I found some examples using either factorization or polynomial solving.

**Example 1**

```
For n(n−1)(n−2)(n−3) = 840

n = 7, -4, (3+i√111)/2, (3-i√111)/2
```

**Example 2**

```
For n(n−1)(n−2)(n−3) = 1680

n = 8, −5, (3+i√159)/2, (3-i√159)/2
```

Both of those examples give 4 results (because both are 4th degree equations), but for my use case I'm only interested in the **natural value**. Also the solution should work for any **sequences size** of consecutive numbers, in other words, `n(n−1)(n−2)(n−3)(n−4)...`

The solution can be an algorithm or come from any open math library. The parameters passed to the algorithm will be the product and the degree (sequences size), like for those two examples the product is 840 or 1640 and the degree is 4 for both.

Thank you

Comment: Does brute force count?

Comment: If it's a product of `k` consecutive numbers, then the `k`th root should be fairly close to `n - k/2`. So use that to make an initial estimate then start searching for an exact number from there.

Comment: What are the parameters that would be passed to the algorithm you are looking for?

Comment: The parameters passed to the algorithm will be 1: the product and 2: the degree

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested only in natural "n" solution then this reasoning may help:

Let's say `n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(n-k) = A`

The solution `n=s`then verifies:

- remainder of A/s = 0
- remainder of A/(s-1) = 0
- remainder of A/(s-2) = 0

and so on

Now, we see that `s` is in the order of `t= A^(1/k)` : A is similar to `s*s*s*s*s...` k times. So we can start with `v= (t-k)` and finish at `v= t+1`. The solution will be between these two values.

So the algo may be, roughly:

```
s= 0
t= (int) (A^(1/k)) //this truncation by leave out t= v+1. Fix it in the loop
theLoop:
for (v= t-k to v= t+1, step= +1)
{   i=0
    while ( i <= k ) 
    {   if (A % (v - k + i) > 0 ) // % operator to find the reminder
            continue at theLoop
        i= i+1
    }
    // All are valid divisors, solution found
    s = v
    break
}
if  (s==0)
    not natural solution
```

Comment: You need to be a bit careful here: being divisible by `s`, `s-1`, ..., `s - k` is certainly necessary, but it's not sufficient to be able to deduce that the number _is_ exactly `s(s-1)...(s-k)`.  (For example: `840` is divisible by `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` and `8`, but it's not equal to `4*5*6*7*8`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good point! However if a number is of the type `a*a*(a-1)(a-2)...` (notice the two "a" factors) then the k-root "t" will be far from the expected one that satisfies `t(t-1)(t-2)...` So the candidates I propose `(t+1, t, t-1, t-2...)` will fail and the final result will be "no solution", Any how, my answer is just an idea that needs to be fixed and polished.

Comment: Yes, but `a*a*(a-1)*...` is far from the only possibility. Consider the case of solving `n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4) = 780`. The method you propose would suggest that `n=6` is a solution, even though `6*5*4*3*2` is `720`, not `780`. I'd propose considering that your method produces "candidates" for a solution, and that for each candidate it should be checked whether it's really a solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- `n is an integer`, and
- `n > 0`, and
- `k < n`

Then approximately:

```
n = FLOOR( (product ** (1/(k+1)) + (k+1)/2 )
```

The only cases I have found where this isn't exactly right is when `k` is very close to `n`.  You can of course check it by back-calculating the product and see if it matches.  If not, it almost certainly is only 1 or 2 in higher than this estimate, so just keep incrementing `n` until the product matches.  (I can write this up in pseudocode if you need it)